# Why do I get a CompletionFailure when building my Android application?

Tags: android, android-studio, realm

I am writing an Android application using Realm. When I first built my application with Gradle, completion failed with the message

```
Creating DefaultRealmModule  
com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure:   
class file java.lang.invoke.MethodType not found
```

What is wrong with it?

I'm using OSX 10.11.3

Running `java --version` gives me

> java version "1.8.0_65"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)

When exploring the issue, I found that when I remove the following lines in build.gradle:

```
compileOptions {
   targetCompatibility 1.8 
   sourceCompatibility 1.8 
}
```

the build succeeded.

Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Are you trying to use the new Jack compiler? Because that will not work with Realm as we use both annotation processing and the Transform API.

Comment: More info can be found here https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2630

Comment: Thanks for your answers,I find out that if I add above-mentioned lines,jack is default enabled.I never consider it's caused by jack before.